# Failed to start Login service after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: upgrade, login, lightdm

I launched the *upgrade* process to **17.10** when asked for it (on 17.04).

My screen was locked (and off) during the download of the packages but it flashed by waking sometimes (I was in the dark so I noticed that).

Then an hour later, I wanted to see how the upgrade went but *I couldn't login* anymore. My **password** was refused (but I could login without problem on a console Ctrl-Alt-F1) so I guess something was wrong with lightDM ?

So I rebooted, and now the boot process fails with `Failed to start Login service` which is not related to *lightDM* anymore but `systemd-logind.service`.

**Edit**:
systemd-logind log shows that:

```
Failed to add match for JobRemoved: Connection timed out
Failed to fully start daemon: Connectin timed out
systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Stopped Login Service.
systemd-logind.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd-logind.serivce: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I can't find much about this on the net

Answer (score 3):

So in fact I must have broken the installation process.

From within a chroot, I run `dpkg --configure -a` as asked by `apt` and I was finally able to boot after a reboot.

Everything seems fine at first sight but I think I am good for a complete reinstall nonetheless.

So this leads to the originial problem. Why couldn't I login after I started the upgrade process ??? This is why I rebooted inthe first place.

Answer (score 1):

Today I had very similar problem. In my case I saw the login screen, but was unable to even enter my password. It immediately reacted with *Authentication failure* (or something like that) to any key press or mouse hit.

I think this is related to the changes introduced with [Ubuntu 17.10](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_Desktop), specifically:

> - The Ubuntu Desktop now uses GNOME instead of Unity.
> - GDM has replaced LightDM as the default display manager. The login screen now uses virtual terminal 1 instead of virtual terminal 7.

I had to enter to recovery mode after reboot. And I also had to run `dpkg --configure -a`, but several times. Possibly it is related to disabled networking and I saw it was unable to stop/start the *NetworkManager* service. So I needed to kill this and some other services-related configurations with `Ctrl-C` and restart `dpkg`.