# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck in the following photo

Tags: 18.04, login

I'm not that much familiar with Ubuntu, and I'm going on with practising.

I was installing docker and docker compose, but when I restart my machine I am stuck in the following screen:

[image: boot messages]

I kindly request you to help me to figure out the issue that causes the problem.

Comment: You may try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/967991/260379).